# can't run applets

Tags: security, java-8, applet, java-7

I'm just following a tutorial about running Java Applets and it seems that, in accordance with this doc https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml, if my simple Applet does not follows the aspects bellow, I can't run a Java Applets on JRE.

```
* Unsigned application

An application without a certificate (i.e. unsigned apps), or missing
application Name and Publisher information are blocked by default. 
Running this kind of application is potentially unsafe and present 
higher level of risk.

* Self-signed application (Certificate not from trusted authority)

An application with self-signed certificate is blocked by default. 
Applications of this type present the highest level of risk because 
publisher is not identified and the application may be granted access 
to personal data on your computer.

* Jar file missing Permission Attribute

Permissions Attribute verifies that the application requests the permission
level that developer specified. If this attribute is not present, it might be
possible for an attacker to exploit a user by re-deploying an application that is 
signed with original certificate and running the application at a different
privilege level.
```

My question is: Is there any workaround to be followed in order to simple run a Java Applet?

Here is my code:

**HelloWorldApplet.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

class HelloWorldApplet {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawString("Hello World!", 5, 25);

    }

}
```

**HelloWorldApplet.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Hello! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <P> My Java applet says:
        <APPLET CODE="HelloWorldApplet.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Obs.: I also tried to use the 'appletviewer' binary on Ubuntu, but no good..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Applets are a dead / mostly-dead technology, so aside from just playing around with code, you are shooting yourself in foot using them. Also, note that if you are using Chrome, applets do not run on any version above 42.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, considering the security concerns, even from Oracle itself.. I know that they plan more significant changes for the whole Java, including Java Applets.. I was just wondering if there is any workaround, just for test purposes, learning, that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to learn do not bother with Applets. Why learn something deprecated? Check out Java Web Start which is still supported. Or, if you are really just trying to learn Java work with regular main applications kicked off at the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)!